# package.json - how to determine what parts of the module are installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I have a project structure like this:

```
__tests__
example
src
.bablerc
.eslintignore
.eslintrd
.gitignore
package.json
package-lock.json
README.md
```

and `package.json` parameters like:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "files": [
    "src/"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "url"
  },
  "jest": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
  }
}
```

When I `npm install` this modules I only get `src` folder with an empty `index.js` file. The goal was to only have the user install all of the `src` folder and not the `example` part since that is an example app. I thought that `"files": ["src/"],` would solve this. However it's not doing what I would expect. I don't see anything that is in the `src` folder. It's empty!

npm docs say:

> The optional files field is an array of file patterns that describes
>   the entries to be included when your package is installed as a
>   dependency. File patterns follow a similar syntax to .gitignore, but
>   reversed: including a file, directory, or glob pattern (*, **/*, and
>   such) will make it so that file is included in the tarball when it’s
>   packed. Omitting the field will make it default to ["*"], which means
>   it will include all file

How do I allow the user to install all of the src folder and ignore the example folder?

I'm on npm `5.6.0` and node `v9.11.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there! Files entry behave like in a line a `.gitignore`. That works:

```
"files": ["src"]
```

For testing purposes, you can run `npm pack --dry-run` to check in the pack reports what files would be included when running `npm install` on the package you're developing.

Comment: Sorry, corrected typo. Yes, remove the `/`. You can test that the files you want are rightly included by running `npm pack`

Comment: hmm when I run `npm pack` on original with the `/` I see what I would expect when installing this as a dependency.

Comment: Does this make a difference if I'm installing through the url so my package.json looks like `"name": "git+https://restofurl#v0.0.1",`

Comment: Why can't you just pick `a-normal-package-name`?

Comment: It's not set up in our internal repo yet? Not sure but it won't install without url

Comment: Why would `npm pack --dry-run` look good but actually install doesn't pull items in?

Comment: Oof we tagged the wrong commit which was empty... works with or without `/`